# How to make GRUB reappear AND detect Windows?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

boot Mint + Windows 10. I wanted to have Ubuntu instead of Mint.
The computer is a HP-EliteBook-Folio-1040-G1 - so new and it seems to have UEFI, not sure though.

I started the Ubuntu installation. Mint was installed in 1 partition, no swap, etc.
There were 3 partitions. 2 ntfs, and 1 ext4.

I removed the ext4 partition, selected free space, create a new mountpoint `/` and started the installation.
The installation could not be started because of the error `No EFI System Partition was found`.
So I create also a swap partition and a 700MB EFI partition ot of that free spaced from the old Mint. The NTFS partitions are intact.

Now the installation was good.

Problem: after restarting the PC it is running immediately Ubuntu. Grub is not appearing.

I would like to have the GRUB loader appear and give the possibility to choose Ubuntu or Windows.

This is the situation:

```
sudo fsblk
[sudo] password for username: 
sudo: fsblk: command not found


sudo df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1,9G     0  1,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           384M  1,8M  382M   1% /run
/dev/sda6        29G  6,2G   21G  23% /
tmpfs           1,9G   25M  1,9G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1,9G     0  1,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1       63M   63M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/loop0      256M  256M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
/dev/loop2       50M   50M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/467
/dev/loop3       30M   30M     0 100% /snap/snapd/8542
/dev/loop4       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1880
/dev/sda3       667M  7,8M  659M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs           384M   68K  384M   1% /run/user/1000


sudo cat /etc/default/grub
[sudo] password for sodhreeqmonique: 
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

The `ntfs` partitions are in `sda1` and `sda2`

**EDIT:**
To answer the comments:
If I press Esc during boot this screen appears:
[image]

When I select F9, the following appears:
[image]

When I click Os boot manager I get:
[image]

**EDIT 2**
I also tried the following:

F9 here:
[image]

Selected Boot from EFI file:
[image]

Selected EFI:
[image]

Selected this one:
[image]

Selected Ubuntu:
[image]

Selected shimx64 and grub:
[image]

Both these two choices start Ubuntu, but not Grub appears

And should it help, here is the bios:
[image]

Can anybody please help?

Comment: Does the solution lie here?: https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time

Comment: Try pressing `shift` when booting..

Comment: It doesn't seem the same problem. Please take a look at the updated question with photos

Comment: I added some photos

Comment: If Windows is booting in UEFI there must be an EFI partition. If Windows is booting in BIOS mode, Windows does not have it's own EFI partition that Ubuntu can use. It is recommended to install Ubuntu in the same mode as Windows so that both OS can use grub to boot. Perhaps try installing Ubuntu in BIOS, (Legacy), mode. In order to do this you must boot the installer USB in BIOS mode.You can google to find a method to confirm the mode Windows is running in.

Comment: Windows is not booting at all now.
When I run boot-repait in Ubuntu, it says that Windows is in Legacy mode and for this reason I have to change UEFI to legacy or with CSM.
It is already in UEFI hybrid with CSM. If I change it to legacy, Ubuntu does not start too.

Comment: If Windows is installed in BIOS/Legacy mode Ubuntu must also be installed in BIOS/Legacy mode if you  want Windows to boot. You can add an EFI partition for Ubuntu, but that won't boot Windows.

Comment: What about.... reinstalling only Windows, and then reinstall grub in order to have dual boot? Would that work? In Windows there is nothing important. In Ubuntu there are programs, and tools configured already, and it would be painful to reinstall Ubuntu.